# How can I publish my Prisma Middleware while importing Prisma types that are not generated yet?

Tags: typescript, npm, prisma

I want to put my Prisma Middleware in a new npm package and publish it.
I added `@prisma/client` to peerDependencies and want to import the generated models in the parent app like this:

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

const model: Prisma.ModelName[]
```

This type will be genenrated in the parent app when running `npx prisma generate` but it's not available yet.
How should I publish the package?

Comment: looking to do someothign similar did you find a solution

Comment: I didn't find anything yet!